# Eliminate folder picker dialogue box when asking to update a sheet (that I do not want updated)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that daily exports between 8-12 Excel workbooks with different names.

In each of these workbooks is a sheet called sheet "A".

These workbooks are placed in a folder on the user's desktop and the VBA will prompt the user to locate said folder. It will then file by file open each workbook and add a sheet called "Enter Construction Data" and then another sheet called "schedule".

When these sheets are opened one at a time it will copy formulas (A1:AZ1000) from a master Excel file (different workbook (which also has sheets named "Enter Construction Data" and "Schedule") and copy them into the workbooks the user placed in the folder on their desktop (the ones that contain sheet "A").

In summary I am adding sheets from a master Excel workbook to other Excel workbooks, then copying formulas into them and breaking the sheet references.

All of the above works, as intended.

However, when I run the code the file picker opens for every workbook twice to update sheet "A". I do not want to edit or update sheet "A" and if I click cancel in the file folder dialogue box, it wont.

My goal is to eliminate the need for the user to select the "cancel" button in the file folder picker dialogue box. (2x's each file times 8 - 12 times a day)

Bonus: Some of my files have arrays and the compatibility checker pops up. Is there is a way to default to convert using VBA?

I believe the error lies in either the `set sh` line or the `set nws` line.

```
Private Sub BtnAddWorksheets_Click()
Dim file_count As Long
Dim file_name As String
Dim check_path As String
Dim count_files As Integer
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

check_path = Navigator.TxtFilePath
MsgBox (check_path)

file_name = Dir(check_path & "\" & "*")

file_count = 0

'MsgBox (check_path & "\" & file_name) - verified this is the full path

Do While file_name <> ""

    'open workbook
    Set MasterWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=check_path & "\" & file_name)
    'The correct Excel file opens

    'Ensure workbook has opened before doing next line of codes
    '
    NewWB.Sheets.Add After:=NewWB.Worksheets(NewWB.Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = ("Enter Construction Data")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Construction Data")
    Set nws = Sheets("Enter Construction Data")

    With sh.Cells.Copy
    End With

    With nws.Cells
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'Eliminate the Previous workbook reference
    Sheets("Enter Construction Data").range("A1:AZ1000").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="[NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False

    Set sh = Nothing
    Set nws = Nothing

    NewWB.Sheets.Add After:=NewWB.Worksheets(NewWB.Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = ("Schedule")

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    Set nws = Sheets("Schedule")

    With sh.Cells.Copy
    End With

    With nws.Cells
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'Eliminate the Previous workbook reference
    Sheets("Schedule").range("A1:AZ1000").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="[NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False

    NewWB.Close (savechanges = False)

    Set MasterWB = Nothing
    Set NewWB = Nothing

    file_count = file_count + 1
    file_name = Dir

    If count_files = file_count Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Loop

count_files = -1

End Sub
```

This dialogue opens two times per worksheet - This is the only thing I am trying to eliminate from the code.

Image showing dialogue from code run.
[image]

Image showing window with error missing source for updating tab "A".
[image]

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` has an `updatelinks` parameter which you can pass `False` to...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open

Comment: I appreciate the article, Iplaced this in the line

```Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=check_path & "\" & file_name, updatelinks:=False)```

Did not work

Comment: I should add that I am a bit of a novice so a little hand holding would be appreciated.

Comment: I misunderstood where the prompts were coming from.  Can you maybe annotate your question to indicate exactly which lines are resulting in a prompt?

Comment: Hello Tim, I believe it occurs somewhere in the following: ```NewWB.Sheets.Add After:=NewWB.Worksheets(NewWB.Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Enter Construction Data")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Construction Data")
    Set nws = Sheets("Enter Construction Data")``` I notice that when I make changes to the line ```ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter Construction Data")``` by changing the end to a number (1) - generates no results, (2) same results, (3) adds "Enter Construction Data" sheet to workbooks, eliminates prompts from sheet A, but doesn't add "Schedule" as needed.

Comment: Not related to your problem but confusing to me was you have wb.Close (savechanges = False) which because you don't have Option Explicit does not produce a compiler error. The logic result is True (and therefore the book is saved) because the variable savechanges is undefined. The code should be wb.Close SaveChanges := True - no brackets and colon before =.

Comment: I suspect the prompts are a result of modifying the links to NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm. Is that workbook open or closed when the macro is run. ? Are there links to any other workbooks on the added sheets  ?

Comment: Hello CDP, for your first response: Originally I had it coded as =True but it would not save. I will try the above
. 
As far as the second comment: the macro is ran from a form created in the file NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm. 

the NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm workbbook has three sheets ("A", "Enter Construction Data", and "Schedule") 

Tab "A" has a shape which runs a macro that simply shows the form "Navigator". Form Navigator has two buttons, the one runs a module called "Get file" which is a simple folder picker dialogue & the other runs the code that you see with no modules (continued below)

Comment: The Tabs "Enter Construction Data" and "Schedule" in the workbook "NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm" hold the format, formulas, etc that I want copied to the other workbooks. I did it this way so that if I make changes to the structure in the future of NavigatorFormBuild's sheets labeled "Enter Construction Data" and "Schedule" that it will reflect in the Workbooks I am copying to without having to modify any VBA. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CDP1802 - You were exactly right on: ```Not related to your problem but confusing to me was you have wb.Close (savechanges = False) which because you don't have Option Explicit does not produce a compiler error. The logic result is True (and therefore the book is saved) because the variable savechanges is undefined. The code should be wb.Close SaveChanges := True - no brackets and colon before =.``` Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The file picker opens because of the links to the master workbook. Remove the `replace` code and add this before the workbook is saved.

```vb
' remove links
msg = ""
aLinks = NewWB.LinkSources
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
    For j = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
        If InStr(aLinks(j), "[NavigatorFormBuild.xlsm]") > 0 Then
            NewWB.BreakLink aLinks(j), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            msg = msg & vbCr & aLinks(j)
        End If
    Next j
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then MsgBox "Links broken " & msg, vbInformation
End If
```

Comment: I commented out the following: ```'''''Eliminate the Previous workbook reference
'Sheets("Enter Construction Data").range("A1:AZ1000").Select
'Selection.Replace What:="[Workbook Converter For Project Update Reports.xlsm]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
'SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
'ReplaceFormat:=False``` I also replaced with your code before the save command,
As instructed. It seems that now it does not break the links at all and additionally the file dialogue picker is still opening twice (followed by an excel compatibility checker dialogue).

Comment: I edited both sets out (i forgot to include that above).

Comment: @Nichowags DId you get the message box showing "Links broken" ?. Move the line msg = msg & vbCr & aLinks(j) to after End If to see all the links.

Comment: it did give me the msgbox once I moved out of the IF Statement, however the file dialogue box still executed before the msgbox (2x's still). The box says: ```Links Broken A and the file path that was selected by the user containing the workbooks.```
However the links are not actually broken in the formulas for the cells on the copied over sheets.

Comment: @nicholwags Can you test by pasting in sheets without links to prove it's not something else.

Comment: I deleted all my data from the sheets named "Enter Construction Data" and "Schedule". I then put in simple text data only (no formulas at all) to test. After running the code you were correct, it performed exactly what I expected it to do without any window prompts. I am not positive if the type of formula could be causing the issue, but for disclosures sake / just in case I am using array formulas with nested if statements inside of them.

Comment: In the "EDITS" section of my original post I added an image of a window that occurs during the code run.

Comment: @nichol I don't understand why the break link is greyed out. Do any formula have [A] in them and are any cells showing #Ref! ?

Comment: I did multiple 'find' searches for the above with no avail in the original sheet as well as sample of the ones I am copying into. Neither the #Ref! or [A] reference was returned. So the data comes from a C# coded program (I am not familiar with that language) and that program does what it is supposed to and compiles the data as an output into an Excel workbook as text data. That data is placed in sheet "A". All the data placed in sheet "A" does not contain any formulas whatsoever.  I am trying to inject into the workbook created 2 sheets, "Enter Construction Data" and "Schedule"

Comment: I was unsure if I was clear in the original post, I figured perhaps the additional background would be beneficial. I am assuming the errors are somewhere in the code I have typed up. The current code is slightly different from above based on recomendations by you and other required enhancements that have no impact to the goal of this thread. I wanted to put that out there for full disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! This website helped me get to the bottom of the problem. 
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/control-startup-message`

This was a multi-faceted problem. First I didn't realize that the sheet index for sheet "A" in the one workbook was (1) and in the other workbook it was (9). To fix this, I simply added a sheet to the workbook missing a sheet index(1) and allowed the default name "Sheet1" to stay. Once I did this, I had a sheet with index (1) in both workbooks. This enabled the "break link" button in the following window:

[Edit Links Window - Referenced in attached article.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzWRl.png)

Next, I clicked the "break link" button and searched the sheets for #REF! as @CDP1802 referenced above. This lead me to a single cell "A1" in the "Enter Construction Data" worksheet. I retyped the formula: `=A!A1` in this cell and the next time I executed the VBA it only opened up the windows compatibility checker (at this point the sheet order was messed up, to fix I simply deleted "Sheet1" - the sheet that was created to get the shared index.) Now the array formulas carry over between workbooks perfectly.

@CDP1802 - your code may have worked to break the links if these indexes were established in both workbooks when I originally tried to run your code. I very much appreciate your help in solving the issues on this!

Final Code:

```
Private Sub BtnAddWorksheets_Click()
Dim file_count As Long
Dim file_name As String
Dim check_path As String
Dim count_files As Integer
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ExcelFileName As String

ExcelFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

check_path = Navigator.TxtFilePath

file_name = Dir(check_path & "\" & "*")

file_count = 0

'MsgBox (check_path & "\" & file_name) - verified this is the full path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While file_name <> ""

'open workbook
    Set MasterWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=check_path & "\" & file_name)

'The correct Excel file opens

'Adds sheet "Enter Construction Data" to workbooks
NewWB.Sheets.Add After:=NewWB.Worksheets(NewWB.Worksheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = ("Enter Construction Data")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set nws = Sheets("Enter Construction Data")

With sh.Cells.Copy
End With


With nws.Cells
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End With

'''''Eliminate the Previous workbook reference
Sheets("Enter Construction Data").Range("A1:AZ1000").Select
Selection.Replace What:="[" & ExcelFileName & "]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

sbProtectSheet

Set sh = Nothing
Set nws = Nothing


'Adds sheet "Schedule" to workbooks
NewWB.Sheets.Add After:=NewWB.Worksheets(NewWB.Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Schedule")

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    Set nws = Sheets("Schedule")

With sh.Cells.Copy
End With



With nws.Cells
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

End With

''''''Eliminate the Previous workbook reference
Sheets("Schedule").Range("A1:CA100").Select
Selection.Replace What:="[" & ExcelFileName & "]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

sbProtectSheet

Worksheets("A").Activate
sbProtectSheet

Worksheets("Enter Construction Data").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

NewWB.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Set MasterWB = Nothing
    Set NewWB = Nothing

file_count = file_count + 1
file_name = Dir

If count_files = file_count Then
count_files = -1
Exit Sub
End If

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload Navigator

End Sub
```

Thank you SO Community!